# What different I need to write in my C# code to make application to work on citrix xenapp?

Tags: installshield, citrix, xenapp

I have to develop a C# application (WPF) and deploy it on Citrix Xenapp server so that a number of users can acccess it. The application is basically like a Windows communicator. I have developed the application and I also have created MSI package using InstallShield. It works well when installed on my machine, but crashes when installed on Citrix machine. 
My question is what specific code (or anything) I need to do for my app to be able to work on Citrix Xenapps?

Comment: What is the error message you are getting on the citrix machine, if any?

Comment: The application crashes while launching.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing special really, Citrix is no more than Terminal Services.

As a rule of thumb I would never use the install path for config/logs and would always do this to user based environment variables.  %USERPROFILE% for example is a good one.

Comment: Do I have to make some registry entries while creating the MSI package?